# Moving unique SQL row IDs into columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following data

```
| PERSON_ID | OBJECT_ID |  VALUE |
|-----------|-----------|--------|
|      1000 |      5511 |   blue |
|      1000 |      5512 |  green |
|      1001 |      6655 | purple |
|      1001 |      6656 | yellow |
|      1001 |      6657 | orange |
```

I want to make a table such that:

```
| PERSON_ID | OBJECT_ID1 | VALUE1 | OBJECTID2 | VALUE2 | OBJECTID3 | VALUE3 |
|-----------|------------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|
|      1000 |       5511 |   blue |      5512 |  green |    (null) | (null) |
|      1001 |       6655 | purple |      6656 | yellow |      6657 | orange |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to `PIVOT`. But you haven't anything  in the base table to pivot on. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It is kind of hypothetical, but I would guess mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the MAX number of OBJECT_ID values there will be per PERSON_ID, try this. Just add more Joins until you reach the MAX number of OBJECT_ID values:

```
select
  p.PERSON_ID,
  o1.OBJECT_ID OBJECT_ID1,
  o1.VALUE VALUE1,
  o2.OBJECT_ID OBJECT_ID2,
  o2.VALUE VALUE2,
  o3.OBJECT_ID OBJECT_ID3,
  o3.VALUE VALUE3
from (select distinct PERSON_ID from t_person_object) p
  left join t_person_object o1
    on o1.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
  left join t_person_object o2
    on o2.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
    and o2.OBJECT_ID > o1.OBJECT_ID
  left join t_person_object o3
    on o3.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
    and o3.OBJECT_ID > o2.OBJECT_ID
group by
  p.PERSON_ID;
```